# Edit model object i form?

Tags: python, django

So i have form what add new object to model Sale what take, id object from model Good and count (count field is in model Good).

What i need. When i create new object in model Sale (with id and count ), change count in model Good with id from model Sale .
so:
goods objects - {id=10 count=5, id=11, count = 3}
create sale -  {d=10 count=3, id=11, count=2}
save sale to model Sale
update good object  {id=10 count = 2 (5-3),id=11 count=1(3-2)} 
update goods from model good
i hope you understand
view

```
  @login_required
    def index(request):
        if request.user.role == '2':
            shop = Shop.objects.get(owner=request.user.parent)
            goods = Good.objects.filter(shop=shop)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SaleForm(request.POST)
                form.fields['good'].queryset = goods
                if form.is_valid():
                    new_form = form.save(commit=False)
                    new_form.seller = request.user
                    new_form.save()
            else:
                form = SaleForm()
                form.fields['good'].queryset = goods

            return render(request, 'base_vendor.html', {'context': goods, 'form': form })
```

form

```
from django import forms
from core.models import Sale


class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ('good', 'count')
```

template

```
<form method="POST" action="{%url 'vendor'%}">
     {% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

## UPD

Sale model

```
  class Sale(models.Model):
        """
        Модель для проданих товарів
        """
        good = models.ForeignKey(Good)
        seller = models.ForeignKey(User)
        time_selling = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
        count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Дані продажу'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Таблиця продажів'
```

Good model

```
class Good(models.Model):
    """
    Модель товарів
    """
    # Налагтувати завантаження зобреження в окрему папку для кожного магазину
    article = models.CharField('Артикул товару', max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField('Назва товару', max_length=100)
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media',blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField('Ціна', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField('Описання товару', max_length=700, default='')
    sale_price = models.DecimalField('Ціна розпродажу', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    producer = models.CharField('Виробник', max_length=100)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товари'
```

Good Form

```
class GoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    article = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control1', 'rows': '30'}))
    price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    sale_price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    producer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    count = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    size = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control1'}))
    image = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Good
        fields = ('article', 'name', 'category', 'image', 'price', 'description', 'sale_price',
                  'producer', 'count', 'size')
```

Add good view.

```
@login_required
def add_good(request):
    if request.user.role == '1':
        try:
            have_shop = Shop.objects.get(owner=request.user.pk)
            if have_shop:
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    form = GoodForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
                        new_form.shop = Shop.objects.get(owner=request.user.pk)
                        new_form.save()
                        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
                else:
                    form = GoodForm()
                    shop = Shop.objects.get(owner=request.user.pk)
                    categories = Category.objects.filter(parent=shop.category.pk)
                    form.fields['category'].queryset = categories

                return render(request, 'add_good.html', {'form': form})
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/setup_shop')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand it, Good contains a count of how many items of that good you have. When you make a Sale you want to subtract that number from the count of goods.

It's actually not that hard:

1. new_form in your example above is actually a Sale object, you you could rename it to sale.
2. I guess the user has selected a good from the goods list you supply to the form. Use your sale object to get the Good that the user selected.
3. Update and save the Good.count in the database.

(Bonus tip: You should use a database transaction for this. If something breaks when a sale is being saved you might end up with an incorrect Good count. A transaction avoids this from happening by rolling things back in case of error)

Comment: thx. i know it but i don`t knpw how realize. I can take good id from form.is_valid(): (i try)   good =  Good.objects.get(pk=form.good.pk)
and how update my new object "good"

Comment: That's not possible to answer without you posting your models and forms too.

Comment: I don't see any code to let the user select a good from a list of goods. Isn't that what you want the user to do first?